# Sharing dictionary with item-level locking in multiprocessing (without Manager)

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I need to share a `dict` object between multiple processes. Each process, at its runtime, will read or modify existing items and/or add new items into the dict. I am using the `manager` object from `multiprocessing` similar to this code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def init_d(d, states):
    for s in states:
        if tuple(list(s) + [0]) not in d:
            for i in range(4):
                d[tuple(list(s) + [i])] = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        master_d = manager.dict()

        states1 = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
        states2 = [(1, 2), (5, 6)]

        p1 = mp.Process(target=init_d, args=(master_d, states1))
        p2 = mp.Process(target=init_d, args=(master_d, states2))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

        print(master_d)
```

However, it is extremely slow for my particular usage. Aside form the fact that Manager is slower than shared memory (according to [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html)), the much more important issue is that in my application, each process read/modify/add only one item of the dict at a time while has nothing to do with the rest. So, instead of locking the entire dict object, which causes the enormous slow-down, I was wondering if there is a way to for example only lock the specific item in `__get_item__` and `__set_item__` methods.

I have seen several related questions, but no answer. Please do not tell me about thread safety and locking stuff. Also, I am NOT looking for the generic case, rather:

1. I need an implementation that allows for reading an item of a dictionary by one process, while modifying another item by another process, also possibly add a new item by yet another process, all at the same time.
2. The `dict` can be extremely large, and I somehow rely on O(1) property of hash tables. Hence, I can not use list or tuple instead.
3. Each process only read/modify/add one item. Hence, a local dict and then updating the shared one at the end (after a batch of local updates) is not an option.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: any solution so far for this problem?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this problem as well.